# find unpaired element in array - how does this work?

Tags: javascript, arrays, find

There was a question on how to find the unpaired element in an array. So if an element occurs in an array 3 times, or 5 times, or any unpaired times.

The fastest method (it works ok!) was this:

```
function pairing (A) {
  var s = new Set; 
  A.forEach(function(v) {
    s.delete(v) || s.add(v)
  });

  return s.values().next().value;
}

const arr = [1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 5, 7, 8, 7, 7, 8, 7, 1, 1, 3];
console.log(pairing(arr));
```

It will give `3` as a result, that's the unpaired element.

The solution works, but I don't know what it does. Please somebody give me an explanation for this!

What is this line:

```
s.delete(v) || s.add(v)
```

I can't interpret it.

And, this one:

```
s.values().next().value;
```

?

Please detail what is happening here.

Thank you !

Comment: So set can have only unique elements in it , try to understand now

Comment: Look at the documentation for Set and understand what delete does. After that learn what the [Logical OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR) does.

Comment: Please read the manual: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Answer (score 1):

The [logical or operator (`||`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR) short-circuits and returns the first value that is not false (or falsey, but that is not relevant here).

[`Set#delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/delete) returns true if the element was deleted, i.e. it did originally exist in the set, and false otherwise. [`Set#add`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/add) returns true if the element was added, i.e. it did not already exist in the set, and false otherwise.

Thus, `s.delete(v) || s.add(v)` is really saying delete `v` if it already exists in the set; otherwise, add it. This works due to the short-circuiting of the logical or operator: if `set.delete(v)` returns true, `s.add(v)` will never be executed.

[`Set#values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/values) returns the iterator for the values of the set in the order they were inserted. `.next()` gets the next element from the iterator and `.value` gets the value of that element. In this case, it returns the first and only element of the `Set`, which is the unpaired element.

On another note, the standard and most efficient way to solve this problem for integers is to apply the [bitwise XOR (`^`) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_XOR). Since `a ^ a === 0` for all integers, simply XORing all the numbers in the array will find the number that appeared an odd amount of times.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 5, 7, 8, 7, 7, 8, 7, 1, 1, 3];
function unpaired(arr){
  return arr.reduce((acc,curr)=>acc^curr,0);
}
console.log(unpaired(arr));
```

Comment: thank you very much for your detailed explanation ! However I still don't get how any why this line

return s.values().next().value;

gives back 3, the only unpaired value ?

Comment: @Invisible55 It returns the only value in the `Set`.

Comment: @Invisible55 Does that answer all your questions?

Comment: Now I understand ! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Invisible55 No problem.

Answer (score 0):

Simplified version of the function you posted. Hope it is understandable now

```js
var set = new Set();
const arr = [1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 5, 7, 8, 7, 7, 8, 7, 1, 1, 3];

arr.forEach(ele => {
    if(set.has(ele)){
        set.delete(ele);
    } else {
        set.add(ele);
    }
})

console.log(set.values().next().value);

 // This gives the element left over in set which is unpaired.
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for your detailed explanation ! However I still don't get how any why this line

return s.values().next().value;

gives back 3, the only unpaired value ?

Comment: s is set , .values() is the method which return the setIterator . So to access the element , .next() method will be used and finally .value will give the actual value left over in the set

Answer (score 0):

s.delete(v) || s.add(v)  - this delete a value if present in a set or add if not already present in a set "s".

s.values().next().value;  - this one return the value left in the set(unpaired one)

### As per the code -

```js
function pairing (A) {
  var s = new Set; 
  A.forEach(function(v) {
    console.log(s)
    s.delete(v) || s.add(v)

  });

  return s.values().next().value;
}

const arr = [1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 5, 7, 8, 7, 7, 8, 7, 1, 1, 3];
console.log(pairing(arr));
```

}

const arr = [1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 5, 7, 8, 7, 7, 8, 7, 1, 1, 3];
console.log(pairing(arr));

### The output is

[image]

Comment: ahhhh, so the set will be reduced to 3 ! because everything that has a match, will be deleted at the end ! - I get iiiiiit !